How do I get a COUNT of rows using UTC grouped by date - but in the end-user's timezone?
I need to write an efficient query from my backend application so that I may know how many online sessions are there (count) per day for a given date range.
Sample input:
Year: 2020, month: 08, timezone: "Asia/Dhaka". <- timezone can be any timezone passed from backend.
Sample output:
[
{"date": "2020-08-01", "online_session_count": 3},
{"date": "2020-08-02", "online_session_count": 0},
{"date": "2020-08-03", "online_session_count": 4},
...... other rows ......
{"date": "2020-08-31", "online_session_count": 1},
]

Here is the table definition:
CREATE TABLE online_speakers (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    speaker_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    start_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    end_time DATETIME NOT NULL
);

Here are some dummy rows:
INSERT INTO online_speakers (speaker_name, start_time, end_time) VALUES
('Speaker 1', '2020-08-01 10:00:00', '2020-08-01 11:00:00'),
('Speaker 2', '2020-08-01 14:00:00', '2020-08-01 15:00:00'),
('Speaker 3', '2020-08-02 09:00:00', '2020-08-02 10:00:00'),
('Speaker 4', '2020-08-03 10:00:00', '2020-08-03 11:00:00'),
('Speaker 5', '2020-08-03 13:00:00', '2020-08-03 14:00:00'),
('Speaker 6', '2020-08-03 15:00:00', '2020-08-03 16:00:00'),
('Speaker 7', '2020-08-04 11:00:00', '2020-08-04 12:00:00'),
('Speaker 8', '2020-08-04 13:00:00', '2020-08-04 14:00:00'),
('Speaker 9', '2020-08-05 10:00:00', '2020-08-05 11:00:00'),
('Speaker 10', '2020-08-05 15:00:00', '2020-08-05 16:00:00');

And here is the query that I wrote:
WITH RECURSIVE date_range AS (
    SELECT DATE('2020-08-01') AS date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    FROM date_range
    WHERE DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= '2020-08-31'
)
SELECT
    date_range.date,
    COALESCE(session_tbl.online_session_count, 0) AS online_session_count
FROM
    date_range
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        DATE(CONVERT_TZ(start_time, 'UTC', 'Asia/Dhaka')) AS date,
        COUNT(*) AS online_session_count
    FROM
        online_speakers
    WHERE
        start_time BETWEEN CONVERT_TZ('2020-08-01 00:00:00', 'Asia/Dhaka', 'UTC')
                      AND CONVERT_TZ('2020-08-31 23:59:59', 'Asia/Dhaka', 'UTC')
    GROUP BY
        date
    ORDER BY
        date
) session_tbl ON session_tbl.date = date_range.date;

As you can see, the where clause is using aggregating functions, which is very inefficient for large tables containing millions of rows. In such scenarios, how do experts tackle the problem?
Any suggestions/improvement to my existing query is also welcome.

@Dai this is a perfectly reasonable thing to ask, returning all the rows for the client to convert tz and count how many are on each day would be silly.

Re "the where clause is using aggregating functions", don't know what you mean by that.  The where clause is exactly what it should be.  Is start_time indexed?  What does explain show?

The order by in the subquery has no effect, remove it.  And while your cte is likely going to cause the results to be in date order, that is not guaranteed; add order by date_range.date at the end.

@ysth The database client (i.e. the OP's application code) should perform the conversion from local time to UTC and pass the converted value to MySQL. As for some kind of `GROUP BY calendarDay" logic, there are solutions, but I need to know more about the OP's application before I can make a suggestion.

@Dai, I always use UTC. but when there is a range based query, how may i know exactly which utc datetime should be my starting point for that user? because he will only send me year and month as an input. if he is GMT +06, that means for year 2020 and month 08, i need to consider the starting datetime: 2020-07-31 18:00:00 (UTC) in my query

@NoobCoder Is this for a desktop application, a web-application, or something else?

@Dai their data is UTC, so presumably they are doing that.  That has nothing to do with generating a report by day in a particular timezones.

@NoobCoder you get your staring point and ending point exactly the way you are doing.  You could calculate those values in your client, but that doesn't save you any time (and risks discrepancies between the exact tzdata version loaded in your database and the version used by your code)

@NoobCoder How many events are there for a given month? Depending on the size of your database (e.g. fewer than a few thousand rows per day? ~30,000 per month?) then it should be fast-enough to just SELECT all events for a month in UTC and convert it in your application code.

@ysth To be fair to MySQL, it can be configured to use its host OS's timezone database (though I'm unsure if this is enabled by default).

I've re-titled this question to reduce misunderstandings - including my own...

@Dai that's just for setting the default connection timezone based on the os timezones, that's not what convert_tz will use (except when given 'SYSTEM')

@ysth The docs say that's what mysql_tzinfo_to_sql is for - not just for connections.

Yes, but that doesn't set it to use the system data on an ongoing basis, just imports the current system data into MySQL.

Again, is start_time indexed? What does explain show?

As a preface, I'll say that this kind of functionality (i.e. grouping by date in a runtime-defined per-request timezone) is actually kinda rare, I don't recall ever seeing feature in any software I've used, actually.
The problem here is that for high-perf you'll need to precompute date-only values and create an INDEX over them - but if you need to apply a per-request calculation to a value which results in different date values then the INDEX will useless and the RDBMS will need to do a full table-scan (or at least a range-scan, which isn't pretty.
Plenty of software, reporting functionality especially, does offer the ability to group by date, but they'll do one of three things:

Use a single (non-UTC) local timezone for everything. This was (and probably still is) how a lot of on-prem software still works, even though it's a bad idea anyway (because local timezone offsets are not immutable), which means it's impossible correctly to map those timestamps back to UTC, and more problems besides.
Use UTC exclusively: users can only see data grouped by UTC date, not their own (local timezone-defined) dates.
In a system where data can be logically partitioned by something that's also associated with a timezone, such as a web-discussion-forum showing a user their own posts-by-day grouped by their own TZ's dates, or (especially) in a multi-tenant system where each tenant has an associated timezone, then the system can determine the date for that tenant and save that with the original UTC timestamp - this column will then indexed and will be very fast when performing a GROUP BY.

The downside common to all 3 approaches is users can't specify a per-request timezone with which to calculate dates for the aggregation's GROUP BY.

In your case, consider if the added complexity of allowing user's to set a per-request timezone for calendar-date calculations is actually worth the effort. Consider alternatives, such as using UTC-only dates and look at your actual user-base to see how many users would be adversely affected (e.g. if your users are within ~6 hours of UTC and most of these online_speakers rows have timestamps between 06:00 and 18:00 then you'll get-away-just-fine with grouping by UTC dates.
Whereas if you really need this functionality, and you need it indexed, then here's how I'd do it:

Side-note: If you were using an RDBMS that supported Materialized Views or Indexed Views (which MySQL 8.x does not support) and if the only query predicates are a date-range and timezone-id, then I'd create separate VIEW objects for each supported timezone-id (I reckon you'd only need about ~30 timezones: 24 for the hour-aligned timezone offsets, and about 6 or so for the non-hour-aligned timezone offsets). Note that you wouldn't necessarily convert values to a specific timezone, instead just apply the offset; I advocate this (despite it not correctly handling DST and timezone changes) because having a VIEW for each timezone-id would be cost-prohibitive for little gain - and any issue can be worked-around by having your application code simply lookup adjustment dates and re-issuing multiple queries for each period between adjustments.
Something like this:
CREATE VIEW online_speakers_daily_counts_P0100 AS
SELECT
    DATE( DATE_ADD( start_time, INTERVAL 1 HOUR ) ) AS start_time_date
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
    online_speakers
GROUP BY
    DATE( DATE_ADD( start_time, INTERVAL 1 HOUR ) );

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ON online_speakers_daily_counts_P0100 ( start_time_date ) INCLUDE ( count );

...then repeat for all the other offsets: +0200, +0300, +0530, -0800, etc. (chars P and N are used to represent the zone's UTC offset + and - sign btw). You'll need to change INTERVAL 1 HOUR too, of course.
So your application-code would do something like this:
let dtRangeStart  : Date = ...
let dtRangeEndExcl: Date = ... // I assuming this is an exclusive-upper-bound and pre-validated such that `dtRangeEnd > dtRangeStart`.
let timezoneId    : IanaTimeZoneId = ...

let timeZoneEventsInRange: List<(DateTime utc, TimeSpan utcOffset)> = getTimeZoneAdjustmentsDuringRange( dtRangeStart, dtRangeEndExcl, timeZoneId );

let allResults = new List<(Date d, Int count)>();

foreach( (DateTime utc, TimeSpan utcOffset) in timeZoneEventsInRange ) {
    let sign: Char = ( utcOffset.totalTicks == 0 ) ? 'Z' : ( utcOffset.totalTicks > 0 ) ? 'P' : 'N';

    let sqlViewName = "online_speakers_daily_counts_{sign}{utcOffset.hh}{utcOffset.mm}";

    if( !doesSqlViewExist( sqlViewName ) ) {
        return Error( "Sorry, $timezoneId is not a supported timezone" 
    );

    let results = execSqlQuery( "SELECT start_time_date, count FROM {sqlViewName} WHERE start_time_date >= {dtRangeStart} AND start_time_date < {dtRangeEndExcl}" );
    allResults.append( results );
}

allResults.sort( (x,y) => x.d - y.d );

printResults( allResults );

Implementing getTimeZoneAdjustmentsDuringRange is an exercise for the reader.
And now back to your problem...

The solution I propose, below, is imperfect: it relies on precomputing an indexable value derived from start_time: but instead of trying to GROUP BY a date, it instead groups events by hour (or by half-hour increments if you want to support that timezone); which means your query will need to transfer at most 24 rows per calendar-day (or 48 rows for 30-min timezones) - your application code then can perform the final aggregation step to group-by-date (or if you want to do it in SQL you can, but profile+benchmark your results, you might be surprised at which approach is faster).
MySQL supports indexing computed-columns just fine, btw.
First, extend your online_speakers table with a new computed column that zeroes-out minutes, seconds, etc; i.e. round start_time down to its current hour (and do not round-up to the nearest hour): start_time_hour:
ALTER TABLE online_speakers
    ADD COLUMN start_time_hour datetime GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
        DATEADD( DATE( start_time ), INTERVAL HOUR( start_time ) HOURS )
    ) STORED NOT NULL;

CREATE INDEX ix_start_time_hour ON online_speakers ( start_time_hour );

Then have a query like this:
(Explanation below)
DECLARE @rangeStartAsUtc   datetime = // Input parameter, derived from the user-input requested range-start calendar date, then converted to a UTC date+time value considering the requested timezone-id
DECLARE @rangeEndExclAsUtc datetime = // Input parameter, exclusive upper-bound.
DECLARE @userUcOffset      time     = // Input parameter, derived from the requested timezone-id, determined by the calling application.
    
WITH rangedEventsCountByHour AS (

    SELECT
        s.start_time_hour, /* Defined above as `DATEADD( DATE( start_time ), INTERVAL HOUR( start_time ) HOURS )` */
        COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM
        online_speakers AS s
    WHERE
        s.start_time_hour >= @rangeStartAsUtc
        AND
        s.start_time_hour <  @rangeEndExclAsUtc
    GROUP BY
        start_time_hour
),
rangedEventsCountByOffsetHours AS (

    SELECT
        DATEADD( s.start_time_hour, @userUcOffset ) AS start_time_user,
        cnt
    FROM
        rangedEventsCountByHour AS s
),
groupedByOffsetDate AS (

    SELECT
        DATE( r.start_time_user ) AS start_date_user,
        SUM( r.cnt ) AS cnt
    FROM
        rangedEventsCountByHour AS r
    GROUP BY
        DATE( r.start_time_user )
)
SELECT
    g.start_date_user,
    g.cnt
FROM
    groupedByOffsetDate AS g;


The query uses named CTEs instead of inner-queries; this is my preference because it makes queries more self-documenting.
This query should be fast, provided the INDEX ix_start_time_hour exists.

If you might be concerned that it will be slow because it's so long or uses a chain of 4 CTEs, remember that SQL queries do not describe a sequence of instructions or any kind of steps to follow. The "depth" of a query is in now way an indication of its performance).

I appreciate that this does look unnecessarily verbose, and I know MySQL lets you use a SELECT's column-expressions in its GROUP BY clause, but I'm not a MySQL expert and I don't know the details so my query above tries to be ISO SQL-compliant for the benefit of other readers.

I'll also admit that this is untested: I don't have access to a MySQL instance with enough suitable data to test this query with right now.





Because the (computed-coumn) online_speakers.start_time_hour is indexed, it means when rangedEventsCountByHour runs, the RDBMS needs only a range-scan of that index and perform the COUNT(*) using the INDEX-alone (so it doesn't need to even read the source TABLE online_speakers).

So this CTE will return the number of online_speakers rows per date+hour.


The rangedEventsCountByOffsetHours CTE performs the conversion of UTC-based start_time_hour to the user's own timezone.

This is done in its own named CTE because I wasn't confident of how MySQL might handle non-matching SELECT exprs+agg vs. GROUP BY exprs clauses). Plus it makes the whole thing easier to understand, imo.


The groupedByOffsetDate CTE is what converts it from user-hours to user-calendar-dates by performing another GROUP BY aggregation, but using SUM(cnt) not COUNT(*)` for obvious reasons.

Because the results from the previous step (rangedEventsCountByOffsetHours) and this step (groupedByOffsetDate) are dependent on variable input, it means these 2 steps can't take further advantage of any INDEX or precomputed columns - so this part is inherently expensive, but remember that the first step (rangedEventsCountByHour) will return at most 24 rows per calendar day (and 0 rows for hours that had no events), so a query covering a whole month will mean 744, and 8,760 for a year  - that's a trivial amount for these CTEs to process.


The final outer SELECT is just there because SQL doesn't let you give a name to the outermost SELECT query for reasons I'll never know.
I'm not using ORDER BY here because in many (if not most?) cases it's faster to sort the results in application-code; it also slows down a system because it means the RDBMS has to first buffer-up all results first, then sort them, before it can return sorted results to the client; but not using ORDER BY means the RDMBS can start returning rows to the client long before it's finished reading/generating the full result-set.


Don't forget that this query is for a single UTC offset, so you need to check if the date-range includes any DST start/end dates, or if any other changes happened to the zone's UTC offset during that period - if so, then you'll need to split the date-range up (at every DST or offset-change date) and run the query for each (uniformly UTC offset) run of dates.


FWIW I think it's 90% likely that the users's existing query is perfectly ok and they either are guessing that it isn't optimal without actual evidence or are missing the needed start_time index to avoid a full table scan.  note that there are several timezones with dst transitions at 15 minute marks, not 30 or 60 (and a lot at 30). so that's 152431 = 11160 blocks of time at most; I'm guessing they'd need 100000 or more records in a month before this approach sees any benefit.

Use a different table to save all timezone value.
UTC timezone value should be '+00:00' and other timezone should be according to that. Like:
'UTC'          : '+00:00'
'Asia/Dhaka'   : '+06:00' 
'Asia/Kolkata' : '+05:30'

Now change your query accordingly...
So, you code should be:

WITH RECURSIVE date_range AS (
    SELECT DATE('2020-08-01') AS date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    FROM date_range
    WHERE DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= '2020-08-31'
)
SELECT
    date_range.date,
    COALESCE(session_tbl.online_session_count, 0) AS online_session_count
FROM
    date_range
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        DATE(CONVERT_TZ(start_time, '+00:00', '+06:00')) AS date,
        COUNT(*) AS online_session_count
    FROM
        online_speakers
    WHERE
        start_time BETWEEN CONVERT_TZ('2020-08-01 00:00:00', '+00:00', '+06:00')
                      AND CONVERT_TZ('2020-08-31 23:59:59', '+00:00', '+06:00')
    GROUP BY
        date
    ORDER BY
        date
) session_tbl ON session_tbl.date = date_range.date;

Output: 

db<>fiddle code: https://dbfiddle.uk/AZBavvxv

The whole point of using an IANA timezones instead of just an offset is for it to work regardless of time of year or dst transitions; changing to offsets is very wrong.

How do you plan to ensure the TimeZone table is kept up-to-date w.r.t. DST, leap-years, leap-seconds, additions, removals?
